# Wordpress (Genesis) Custom Featured image loads a wrong size

Tags: wordpress, image, size, thumbnails, wordpress-featured-image

I can not get my featured image to load the proper size of image file. It loads a huge image and displays it as a tiny Thumbnail, which I believe slows down the website.

The theme I use is http://wpdemos.info/prima-donna-fashion/. (See the Recent Posts on the sidebar, where the thumbnails are only 100px in width) I want the images to be loaded in the EXACT size(100px width) .

Here is what I tried:

- In functions.php I added a new image size:
  `add_image_size( 'sidebar-100px', 100, 9999, FALSE );`
- Regenerated Thumbnails with Force Regenerate Thumbnails plugin;
- In post_widget.php I select the right image to be displayed:
  `the_post_thumbnail('sidebar-100px');`

Now it loads a better image file, but still NOT the one I generated!

Here is an output:

```
<img src="http://tm.dev/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Nomads.jpg"
     class="attachment-sidebar-100px size-sidebar-100px wp-post-image" alt="Nomads"
     srcset="http://tm.dev/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Nomads.jpg 1300w,
             http://tm.dev/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Nomads-300x138.jpg 300w,
             http://tm.dev/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Nomads-768x354.jpg 768w,
             http://tm.dev/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Nomads-1024x473.jpg 1024w,
             http://tm.dev/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Nomads-1200x554.jpg 1200w,
             http://tm.dev/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Nomads-100x92.jpg 100w,
             http://tm.dev/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Nomads-786x363.jpg 786w"
     sizes="(max-width: 100px) 100vw, 100px" width="100" height="46">
```

I would be really grateful for any advice. Thank you!